# Python: Is there a way to parse a tuple in filter?

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
def important_predicate(tuple_):
    n1, n2 = tuple_
    return ...

list_of_tuples = [(i, some_function(i)) for i in range(..)]
important_group = list(filter(important_predicate, list_of_tuples))
```

The fact that I have to parse the tuple_ into n1, and n2 to be able to use the 2 numbers is rather annoying. I don't want to use tuple_[0], tuple_[1] because n1 and n2 could be named into something important. Is there anything we can do to remove this? Could we apply the concept of "unpacking" of python here? The rough I idea I have is:

```
def some_function(n1, n2):
    return -1

tuple_ = (1, -1)
some_function(*tuple_)
```

But, applied to python built-in filter. I would find suggestion of moving some_function into important_predicate function unhelpful - as it is important to keep the list_of_tuples for something else. So this is not what I'm looking for:

```
def important_predicate(n1):
    n2 = some_function(n1)
    return ...

list_of_tuples = [(i, some_function(i)) for i in range(..)]
important_group = list(filter(important_predicate, list_of_tuples))
```

Comment: [`starfilter`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/starfilter.html)?

Comment: How about a list-comp instead of `filter`? `important_group = [tup for tup in list_of_tuples if pred(*tup)]`

Comment: Use *another* function which applies the tuple as arguments to the predicate: `lambda t: predicate(*t)`. But just use a list comprehension.

Comment: @Tomerikoo list comprehension works (and my understanding is it's "pythonic" to prefer list comprehension over list and filter) but I would still like to know the answer to question (what if it's a code-base where list and filter is more prevalent over list?)

Comment: @superbrain yes - starfilter, but as a standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution because I like [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress). And [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) does that kind of unpacking.

```
from itertools import starmap, compress

def important_predicate(n1, n2):
    return n1 == n2

list_of_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
important_group = list(compress(list_of_tuples,
                                starmap(important_predicate, list_of_tuples)))

print(important_group)
```

Output:

```
[(2, 2)]
```

Appears to be faster than the other answer's solution and also faster than a list comprehension:

```
0.46 s  compress_starmap
0.93 s  filter_lambda
0.65 s  list_comprehension

0.46 s  compress_starmap
0.92 s  filter_lambda
0.65 s  list_comprehension

0.46 s  compress_starmap
0.91 s  filter_lambda
0.73 s  list_comprehension
```

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from itertools import starmap, compress

def important_predicate(n1, n2):
    return n1 == n2

def compress_starmap():
    return list(compress(list_of_tuples, starmap(important_predicate, list_of_tuples)))

def filter_lambda():
    return list(filter(lambda tuple_: important_predicate(*tuple_), list_of_tuples))

def list_comprehension():
    return [tuple_ for tuple_ in list_of_tuples if important_predicate(*tuple_)]

list_of_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)] * 1000

for _ in range(3):
    for func in compress_starmap, filter_lambda, list_comprehension:
        t = min(repeat(func, number=1000))
        print('%.2f s ' % t, func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Docs for [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) and [`mapstar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be more in line with what I wanted to ask (and my upvote seems not to affect public rating because I don't have 15 ratings yet ;))

While it seems to be the best solution so far (and I have to add it's very unique and I feel I've learned something!) I was wondering if we can do anything about list_of_tuples twice

Comment: @dyxogus What's the issue with list_of_tuples twice? If you don't like it in your main code, you could always write your own `starfilter` function (and "hide" the duplication in there, or use any of the other solutions in it).

Comment: @superbrain true, or even as you said - use starfilter. While I think the solution is really clever, it uses 2 different mechanisms (compress and mapstar) and the alternative is either to make my own function or import a library just for it. For personal projects, it works perfectly, but for code-maintainability in live production, I'll probably go with list comprehension at this point. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack in a lambda expression like so:

```py
important_group = list(filter(lambda tuple_: important_predicate(*tuple_), list_of_tuples))
```